# Convert float number into binary

Tags: python

```
import struct
def print_binary(number_string):
    bin = ""   
    if "." in number_string:
        number_string = float(number_string)
        bin += bin(struct.unpack('!i',struct.pack('!f', number_string)))
    else:
        num = int(number_string)  
        bin += "{0:b}".format(num)
    print(bin)
```

I'm having trouble with converting a number with a decimal in it to binary (my if statement)

```
test_values = "0 1234 -1234 12.4 0.6 -12.4 -0.6 -1234567890.123456789".split()
```

I get an error when it gets up to 12.4

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "convert float number to binary"? You can't pack a string as a float, and I'm not sure why you'd even want to pack a float and then unpack the first half of the result as an int, so… it's very hard to guess what this is even trying to do.

Comment: Do you have the same assignment as [this questioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49393540/float-to-binary-floating-point) a few hours ago? That question is even more incomplete, but it does have some info you're missing—like at least one example of input and desired output.

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for some help on how to ask a good question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about converting a decimal number to binary

Comment: Did you read the linked help article? Do you just not know how to give us sample input and desired output?

Comment: My initial answer below did not include the cases of "-.7" and ".7" where there are no preceding 0. Now it should cover all cases.

Answer (score 0):

I used recursion. But there can be a recursion limit on some value here.

Here is the method I used by hand.

```
Fractional Part = .6875 in base 10
.6875*2 equals 1.375  whole number is 1
.375*2 equals 0.75    whole number is 0
.75*2 equals 1.5      whole number is 1
.5*2 equals 1.0       whole number is 1
Hence .6875D = .1011 in base 2
```

However, think about the value 12.4. It will go forever!

```
.4*2 = .8
.8*2 = 1.6
.6*2 = .2
.2*2 = .4
... and so on
```

So we have to set a limit in our recursion calculation. I made it 10. Although this does not sound like a lot, see how accurate it is.

My input of 12.4 returns 1100.0110011001 which is equal to 12.3994140625

Pretty close, feel free to play with that number, take the ceiling of it, etc.

Here is the code:

```
def get_integer_part(pre_decimal_string):
    # special case of negative 0 being a prefix "-0.6"
    if pre_decimal_string == "-0":
        return "-0"
    else:
        num = int(pre_decimal_string)
        return "{0:b}".format(num)


def get_decimal_part(post_decimal_string, string_builder, recurse):
    recurse += 1
    post_decimal_value = float("." + post_decimal_string)

    if post_decimal_value == 0 or recurse > 10:
        return string_builder
    else:
        temp_mult_str = str(post_decimal_value * 2)
        temp_mult_split = temp_mult_str.split(".")
        string_builder += temp_mult_split[0]
        return get_decimal_part(temp_mult_split[1], string_builder, recurse)


def print_binary(number_string):
    # handle case of no preceding 0 ".3" or
    if number_string[0] == ".":
        number_string = "0" + number_string

    # handle case of no preceding 0 and is negative
    if number_string[0:2] == "-.":
        number_string = "-0" + number_string[1:]

    if "." in number_string:
        str_split = number_string.split(".")
        print(get_integer_part(str_split[0]) + "." + str(get_decimal_part(str_split[1], "", 0)))
    else:
        print(get_integer_part(number_string))

test_values = "0 1234 -1234 12.4 0.6 -12.4 -0.6 -1234567890.123456789".split()
print(test_values)
for each in test_values:
    print_binary(each)

# special cases
print_binary("-.7")
print_binary(".67")
```

Here is the final output:

```
0
10011010010
-10011010010
1100.0110011001
0.1001100110
-1100.0110011001
-0.1001100110
-1001001100101100000001011010010.0001111110
-0.1011001100
0.1010101110
```

Although I would have done this differently, I kept your code and format as much as possible to make it easiest for you to learn.